# i there a simple way to get these json values using python 3

Tags: python, json, tuples

EDIT: used the suggested solution, now the json has more headers, as shown bellow.

I have input file as Json,

```
{
    "systems-under-test": [{
            "type": "url",
            "sytems": [
                "www.google.com",
                "www.google.com",
                "www.google.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "api",
            "sytems": [
                "api.com",
                "api.fr"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ip",
            "sytems": [
                "172.168 .1 .1",
                "172.168 .1 .0"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "headers-configuration": [{
        "custom": true,
        "headers-custom-configuration": {
            "headers": [{
                    "header-name": "x - frame - options",
                    "ignore": false,
                    "expected-value": ["deny", "sameorigin"]
                },
                {
                    "header-name": "content-security-policy",
                    "ignore": false,
                    "expected-value": []
                }
            ]
        }
    }],
    "header-results": []
}
```

after using the suggested solution by, I created dict that stores each header information and added these dict to a list.
for a single header in Json works fine, when I have multi headers its not working.

```
     def load_header_settings2(self):
        header_custom_setting = []
        newDict = {}

        path = self.validate_path()
        with open(path) as json_file:
            data = load(json_file)
            config = data["headers-configuration"][0]
            if config["custom"]:
                headers = config["headers-custom-configuration"]["headers"]
                headers_name = headers["header-name"]
                ignore = headers["ignore"]
                expected_values = headers["expected-value"]

                newDict["header name"] = headers_name
                newDict["ignore"] = ignore
                newDict["expected value"] = expected_values
                header_custom_setting.append(newDict)
                newDict.clear()
                for i in header_custom_setting:
                    print(i)
                return header_custom_setting
```

can someone help?

Comment: provide the needed output JSON

Comment: I'd like to help but unfortunately I have no clear idea what you're trying to do and what your difficulties exactly are. Could you explain that in a bit more detail?

Comment: I managed to fix it , thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get both header name and values like this, making sure we check `"custom"` is set to `true` before proceeding:

```
from json import load

with open("data.json") as json_file:
    data = load(json_file)
    config = data["headers-configuration"][0]

    if config["custom"]:
        headers = config["headers-custom-configuration"]["headers"]

        headers_name = headers["header-name"]
        print(headers_name)

        expected_values = headers["expected-value"]
        print(expected_values)
```

**Output:**

```
x - frame - options
['deny', 'sameorigin']
```

As for concatenating the headers and values, you could iterate the headers and values and combine them together into a string:

```
for value in expected_values:
    print("%s %s" % (headers_name, value))
```

Or using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#id43):

```
for value in expected_values:
    print(f"{headers_name} {value}")
```

Which will give you:

```
x - frame - options deny
x - frame - options sameorigin
```

Comment: in case I changed my json to have multiple headers like ```"headers": [{
     "header-name": "x - frame - options",
     "ignore": false,
     "expected-value": ["deny", "sameorigin"]
    },
    {
     "header-name": "content-security-policy",
     "ignore": false,
     "expected-value": []
    }
   ]``` how I can make sure all headers are added ?

Comment: @Ibrahim What is the expected result of that?

Comment: im thinking to store headername, ignore and expected-value in dictionary per each header, and store these dictionaries in list , I'm new to python so not so if this good approach

Comment: @Ibrahim What about a dictionary like this: `{'x - frame - options': ['deny', 'sameorigin'], 'content-security-policy': []}`?

Comment: something like ['header-name' : 'x - frame - options', 'expected-value': '['deny', 'sameorigin'], ''ignore'':false] , another dictionary ['header-name' : ontent-security-policy', 'expected-value': '['none'], ''ignore'':false] and so on , because i hv 7 header needs to be added , thanks for the help

Comment: `['header-name' : 'x - frame - options', 'expected-value': '['deny', 'sameorigin'], ''ignore'':false]` is not a valid dictionary. It has `[]` brackets instead of `{}`. My solution makes more sense here because it matches each header with the expected values,and is stored in a dictionary.

Comment: how i can reach this when there are more headers in JSON, i have updated the main question and json

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved like this, is this safe way to reach my goal ?@ RoadRunner

```
    def load_header_settings2(self):
        header_custom_setting = []
        newDict = {}

        path = self.validate_path()
        with open(path) as json_file:
            data = load(json_file)
            config = data["headers-configuration"][0]
            if config["custom"]:
                headers = config["headers-custom-configuration"]["headers"]
                for header in headers:
                    headers_name = header["header-name"]
                    ignore = header["ignore"]
                    expected_values = header["expected-value"]

                    newDict["header name"] = headers_name
                    newDict["ignore"] = ignore
                    newDict["expected value"] = expected_values
                    header_custom_setting.append(newDict)
                    for i in header_custom_setting:
                        print(i)

                return header_custom_setting
```

Comment: That looks fine. I'll make sure to upvote your answer tomorrow :)